# How to check typeof / isntanceof for SafeHtml in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a variable of type string or SafeHtml and I have a method which checks, if the param is of type string or SafeHtml. Based upon the type of the param I want to do different stuff. I tried  `instanceof` and `typeof` but both seem not to be working for `SafeHtml`. How can i check, if a variable is of type `SafeHtml`?

```
public isSafeHtml(value: string | SafeHtml) {
    if (typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String) {
        // ..stuff for case string
    }
    if (typeof value === 'SafeHtml' // not working
        || value instanceof SafeHtml) // not working
    {
        // ..stuff for case SafeHtml
    }
}
```

`typeof` seems to be working only for basic types, such as 'string' | 'number' | ...
[image]

`instanceof SafeHtml` isn't working because 'SafeHtml' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here?
[image]

Comment: You can't. `SafeHtml` is just an empty interface. There is nothing that could differentiate something of type `SafeHtml` from anything else at runtime. And since `SafeHtml` might as well be a `string`, checking `if (typeof value === 'string')` can give you false positives which might not be okay depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SafeHtml` is an interface for a type, since your union is a simple `string | SafeHtml` you just need to check for the string:

```
public isSafeHtml(value: string | SafeHtml) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    // ..stuff for case string
    return;
  }

 // ..stuff for case SafeHtml
}
```

Comment: sounds legit! I put the stuff for case SafeHtml into the else clause, since this method shall not return anything.

Comment: @MojioMS that's another correct way. Just keep in mind that `return;` can be used in void functions